# Cannot install SBT plugin for IntelliJ 12.1.6 CE on Mac

Tags: scala, plugins, intellij-idea, sbt

I would like to install the SBT plugin in IntelliJ 12.1.6 Community Edition (Mac) found here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/

But after adding the repo I tried to install sbt-intellij-bin-0.1.5.8 but the download fails.

What might be the source of the problem?

Comment: I haven't installed the plugin before so I'm guessing. Can you check if you can access http://download.jetbrains.com/scala/sbt-intellij-bin-0.1.58.zip? Can you download it manually after you've downloaded the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest nightly version of the SBT plugin is not compatible with IDEA 12 anymore, only IDEA 13. If you download it manually and try to install an error message stating that will pop up, but for some reason (probably a bug) it isn't really visible when installing from a repository.